# How to join the U.S stock market?

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, south-africa

I am from South Africa.  I want to find out how to join the U.S stock market as a foreigner.  I am currently a musician, a piano player, but trying to explore opportunities to join the financial trading industry.  There are lots of scams out there, so please do give me ideas on where to start.

Comment: You say there are lots of scams out there, and you are asking for advice on the internet?

Comment: Are you looking to join the industry as a professional or invest in the market as an amateur? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score -2):

Open a brokerage account that lets you trade CFDs on US equities. This is a popular way people outside of the US trade the price movements of US stocks.

Comment: In general, foreigners aren't restricted from buying U.S.-listed stock. (Speaking from experience.) Without substantiation, I would challenge your assertion that CFDs are the *primary* way access U.S. stock markets.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea okay I changed the word "primary" since I can't substantiate it either. CFDs offer advantages especially for cross border regulations, but are not offered or liquid in within the US due to US nuances. Foreigners may not have a problem getting accounts on with brokerages that have US equities, but people generally want to trade everything from one account or have better leverage for risk management.

Comment: From my Canadian discount broker account, I can buy U.S. equities directly, employ margin, as well as trade U.S.-listed options ... here I see no need for CFDs to employ leverage. CFDs are available in my jurisdiction, but IMHO, CFDs are nothing more than a fancy acronym for spread bets, and "CFD provider" nothing more than an attempt at giving a better name to what is essentially a bucket shop. There may be specific features of interest to some traders only available in CFDs, but IMHO they are more harm than good in the marketplace.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea thats nice but your risk averse preference has nothing to do with the validity of this answer.